# Outlook 365 - Connectivity Test Failed

Tags: email, outlook, office365, connectivity

I'm a new of Outlook setting. Therefore, I have problem with outlook setting or outlook synce because when I tried to verify via https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ then got failed result.
For result, let me put them below:

The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to test Autodiscover for bouasone.vongphachanh@roomtoread.org.
    Testing Autodiscover failed.

```
Additional Details
```

Elapsed Time: 24751 ms.

```
Test Steps

Attempting each method of contacting the Autodiscover service.
The Autodiscover service couldn't be contacted successfully by any method.

Additional Details

Test Steps

Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://roomtoread.org:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Additional Details

Test Steps
Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover.roomtoread.org:443/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Additional Details

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.roomtoread.org in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
```

IP addresses returned: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Elapsed Time: 7595 ms.
    Testing TCP port 443 on host autodiscover.roomtoread.org to ensure it's listening and open.
    The specified port is either blocked, not listening, or not producing the expected response.
     Tell me more about this issue and how to resolve it

```
Additional Details
```

A network error occurred while communicating with the remote host.
Elapsed Time: 9860 ms.
    Attempting to contact the Autodiscover service using the HTTP redirect method.
    The attempt to contact Autodiscover using the HTTP Redirect method failed.

```
Additional Details

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover.roomtoread.org in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
Testing TCP port 80 on host autodiscover.roomtoread.org to ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.

Additional Details
The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is checking the host autodiscover.roomtoread.org for an HTTP redirect to the Autodiscover service.
The redirect (HTTP 301/302) response was received successfully.

Additional Details
Attempting to test potential Autodiscover URL https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml
Testing of this potential Autodiscover URL failed.

Additional Details

Test Steps

Attempting to resolve the host name autodiscover-s.outlook.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Additional Details
Testing TCP port 443 on host autodiscover-s.outlook.com to ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.

Additional Details
Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.
The certificate passed all validation requirements.

Additional Details

Test Steps
Checking the IIS configuration for client certificate authentication.
Client certificate authentication wasn't detected.

Additional Details
Attempting to send an Autodiscover POST request to potential Autodiscover URLs.
Autodiscover settings weren't obtained when the Autodiscover POST request was sent.

Additional Details

Test Steps

The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to retrieve an XML Autodiscover response from URL https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml for user bouasone.vongphachanh@roomtoread.org.
The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer failed to obtain an Autodiscover XML response.

Additional Details
```

An HTTP 401 Unauthorized response was received from the remote Unknown server. This is usually the result of an incorrect username or password. If you are attempting to log onto an Office 365 service, ensure you are using your full User Principal Name (UPN).
HTTP Response Headers:
request-id: 3d3f9acd-0b01-46c1-b63a-a0b0c31d01d4
X-CalculatedBETarget: dm5pr01mb2393.prod.exchangelabs.com
X-FEServer: DB6PR07CA0162
Content-Length: 0
Cache-Control: private
Date: Tue, 20 Feb 2018 03:09:37 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Basic Realm=""
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Elapsed Time: 936 ms.

Actually, in other email was worked well. just get stuck in this email only.
Should me configure any in Active Directory?
Are there any one that can break it out for me or even suggest the solution then would very appreciate.

Big thanks,
Best regards,
SmallCorner